# How to add "replicas" from Kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-dashboard

I have made a kubernetes cluster and also deployed a dashboard for the same (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/). I want to scale (up and down) my deployment very frequently. Locally, i am using below command to handle the requirement:

example:

```
kubectl scale --replicas=200 deployment hello-world-deployment

kubectl scale --replicas=40 deployment hello-world-deployment
```

**Is it possible to have a button/input field on Dashboard, where i can just enter my value and it does the magic automatically.**

Answer (score 2):

I am able to see an option of "**Scale**" on the "hello-world-deployment" deployment section on kubernetes. Here we can enter the number of our choice to scale up/down.

Somehow, was only able to see "Edit/Delete" option, but after reconfiguring the kubernetes dashboard, i am able to see "**Scale/Edit/Delete**" option.